Split cell into three columns without losing leading zero
I have a column with a phone numbers without hyphens. I am using text to columns to latter recombine the numbers with hyphens but it's dropping leading zeros in the last cell.

You are seeing leading zeros only because I added them in. I used fixed width, created breaks where hyphens go, general for data format, and finish.

When you do text to columns on the final step you will want to choose Text as the ouput type.

Do you really need the hyphens? Would using the custom format for phone numbers work (i.e., just have hyphens display for your column)?

@bugdrown hope you don't mind me saying, but OP is not looking to format the cells, instead they are trying to split the data by column wise using delimiter as hyphen, now if you use custom formatting it will be facade, because the underlining cells remains same, only display changes. To split they will need the formatting to be changed using a formula or using other methods other than custom formatting.

@Mayukh Bhattacharya, thanks for your comment but my question was directed at OP. I'll wait for their response.

I suggest you use the formula =REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, 4, 0, "-"),8,0,"-")


To add hyphens can use one of the following methods:
Using TEXT() functions:


Option One:
=TEXT(B1,"000-000-0000")


Option Two:
=TEXT(B1,"000\-000\-0000")


And to split the data using formula use one of the followings:


The above shows directly splitting without adding hyphens:
=MID(B1,{1,4,7},{3,3,4})


To Split when there are hyphens:


=TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-")


To Split the whole range dynamically without copying down applicable to MS365


=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("-"&A1:A5,"-",{1,2,3}),"-")


To Split using Text To Columns:



First ensure the cells in column A are not formulated, if formulated should make it value pasted that is without formulas.
Select the range, goto Data Tab --> Select Text To Columns
First Step --> Select Delimited --> Click Next
Second Step --> Select Other --> And enter - --> Click Next
Third Step --> Select All the three columns in the Data Preview to be highlighted, and from Column Data Format --> Click Text --> Don't forget to change the Destination --> I have changed it to C1
Finish --> Done.


